# MongoDb with .NET driver add collection jsonschema validation

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there any way, when creating a collection in mongodb with the .NET driver, to specify a json schema to validate against?

I have found documentation on how to set a validator using code, but not how to use a json schema to validate.

The reason I'm looking for schema validation in using the .NET driver is that specifying validation using code gets kind of verbose:

```
db.CreateCollectionAsync(
   "Foos",
   new CreateCollectionOptions<Foo> 
   { 
      Validator = FilterDefinitionBuilder<MongoCustomization>()
        .And(
            new FilterDefinitionBuilder<MongoCustomization>().Exists(c => c.Revision),
            new FilterDefinitionBuilder<MongoCustomization>().Type(c => c.Revision, BsonType.Int32),
            new FilterDefinitionBuilder<MongoCustomization>().Exists(c => c.CreatedBy)), 
      ValidationAction = DocumentValidationAction.Error, 
      ValidationLevel = DocumentValidationLevel.Strict
   });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few years late but the answer is to use the JsonSchema method of the FilterDefinitionBuilder class. Like this:

```
    db.CreateCollectionAsync(
       "Foos",
       new CreateCollectionOptions<Foo>
       {
           Validator = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Foo>().JsonSchema(BsonDocument.Parse("your JSON goes here")),
           ValidationAction = DocumentValidationAction.Error,
           ValidationLevel = DocumentValidationLevel.Strict
       });
```

Comment: Well, I haven't been using MongoDb since 2019... but of course +1 for trying to reduce the amount of unanswered questions on SO. I was looking for a ".NET fluent way" to add validations, but, as with several things in the .NET API, you  just have to resort to bson documents

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to create a JavaScript file and then run it with the Mongo Shell that comes with MongoDB.

This doesn't use the .NET Driver as requested, but I suspect covers anyone's needs.

See: [Write scripts for the mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)

To run a script from the CMD line:

```
> cd "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin"     <--- your mongo bin directory
> mongo path-to-script.js
```